# Join tables with rows to columns conversion

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

[image: TABLE1]

[image: TABLE2]

Output need to be like this:

[image: OUTPUT]

```
select CODE, NAME,
   substring_index(DVAR, ',', 1) as DATA1,
   (case when numc >= 2 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 2), ',', -1) end) as DATA2,
   (case when numc >= 3 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 3), ',', -1) end) as DATA3,
   (case when numc >= 4 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 4), ',', -1) end) as DATA4,
   (case when numc >= 5 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 5), ',', -1) end) as DATA5,
   (case when numc >= 6 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 6), ',', -1) end) as DATA6,
   (case when numc >= 7 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 7), ',', -1) end) as DATA7,
   (case when numc >= 8 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 8), ',', -1) end) as DATA8,
   (case when numc >= 9 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 9), ',', -1) end) as DATA9,
   (case when numc >= 10 then substring_index(substring_index(DVAR, ',', 10), ',', -1) end) as DATA10
    FROM (
    SELECT T2.CODE, T1.NAME,  GROUP_CONCAT(T2.DATA SEPARATOR ',') AS DVAR, count(*) as numc
    FROM TABLE2 AS T2
    LEFT JOIN TABLE1 AS T1 ON T1.CODE=T2.CODE
    GROUP BY T2.CODE
         ) t
```

I used this code in MySQL and its working.

But I don't know how to do in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: You lack any aggregation. A `GROUP By` without any aggregation is pointless (in my opinion MySQL severely flawed that it allows implied aggregation/grouping). You likely want `MAX`.

Comment: Please avoid using images to display data. Instead use formatted text, and ideally DDL+DML for sample data.

Comment: @DaleK sorry. I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` for a similar effect, eg

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
    Code    CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    [Name]  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
    Code    CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    [Data]  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO tbl1 ( Code, [Name] )
VALUES
    ( 'ST101', 'Item1' ),
    ( 'ST102', 'Item2' ),
    ( 'ST103', 'Item3' ),
    ( 'ST104', 'Item4' ),
    ( 'ST105', 'Item5' )


INSERT INTO tbl2 ( Code, [Data] )
VALUES
    ( 'ST101',  '12345' ),
    ( 'ST101', '123456' ),
    ( 'ST101', '123123' ),
    ( 'ST101',  '12412' ),
    ( 'ST105', '123123' ),
    ( 'ST105',     '11' ),
    ( 'ST105',  '51231' ),
    ( 'ST105', '411123' ),
    ( 'ST103', '112312' ),
    ( 'ST103',  '51231' ),
    ( 'ST103', '442424' ),
    ( 'ST103',   '4233' ),
    ( 'ST103',  '23123' ),
    ( 'ST103',   '1231' ),
    ( 'ST104',  '12312' ),
    ( 'ST102',   '1231' ),
    ( 'ST102',  '51231' ),
    ( 'ST102',  '66452' ),
    ( 'ST102',  '51115' )
GO






;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    t1.Code, 
    t1.[Name], 
    t2.[Data], 
    'Data' + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY t1.Code ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS VARCHAR(20) ) rn
FROM tbl1 t1
    INNER JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.Code = t2.Code
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
PIVOT ( MAX( Data ) For rn In ( Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5, Data6, Data7, Data8, Data9, Data10 ) ) pvt
```

If the number of data items is greater than 10 or unknown you should look at dynamic pivot.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.Actually, I think I don't need more than 5.